# reactjs if condition inside the jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

How to do if/else condition in reactjs? I just want that if the `u.status` is 0 the result will display deactivate button, and if not activate

```
        {u.status == '0' (
              <Tooltip title="Deactivate">
                  <IconButton 
                          aria-label="Deactivate"
                          color="primary"
                          size="small"
                          className={classes.deactivateButton}
                          onClick={() => {handleDeactivate(u.groupsid)}}
                      >  
                      <HighlightOffIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
        ):(
          <Tooltip title="Deactivate">
          <IconButton 
                  aria-label="Deactivate"
                  color="primary"
                  size="small"
                  className={classes.ActivateButton}
                  onClick={() => {handleActivate(u.groupsid)}}
              >  
              <HighlightOffIcon />
              </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        )

        }
```

this is the error

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ternary conditional operator uses  a `?` after the condition to be checked.

`condition ? return if condition true : return if condition is false`

Use this :

```
{u.status == '0' ? (
              <Tooltip title="Deactivate">
                  <IconButton 
                          aria-label="Deactivate"
                          color="primary"
                          size="small"
                          className={classes.deactivateButton}
                          onClick={() => {handleDeactivate(u.groupsid)}}
                      >  
                      <HighlightOffIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                </Tooltip>
        ):(
          <Tooltip title="Deactivate">
          <IconButton 
                  aria-label="Deactivate"
                  color="primary"
                  size="small"
                  className={classes.ActivateButton}
                  onClick={() => {handleActivate(u.groupsid)}}
              >  
              <HighlightOffIcon />
              </IconButton>
        </Tooltip>
        )

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ternary operator as mentioned by [Tushar Shahi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10140124/tushar-shahi)

It would be a better practice to do strict equality comparison here (===) to avoid number/string coersion for the string "0" and the number 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use "?"

condition ? executed if true : executed if false

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `&&` here if the right-side expression is dependent on the left side of `&&` i.e if the right-side expression should run if and only if the left side is `true` or contains `truthy` value

```
{
  u.status === '0' && ...
}

{
  u.status !== '0' && ...
}
```

I think this is more readable

```
// u.status === "0" 
{
  u.status === "0" && (
    <Tooltip title="Deactivate">
      <IconButton
        aria-label="Deactivate"
        color="primary"
        size="small"
        className={classes.deactivateButton}
        onClick={() => {
          handleDeactivate(u.groupsid);
        }}
      >
        <HighlightOffIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}

//u.status !== "0"
{
  u.status !== "0" && (
    <Tooltip title="Deactivate">
      <IconButton
        aria-label="Deactivate"
        color="primary"
        size="small"
        className={classes.ActivateButton}
        onClick={() => {
          handleActivate(u.groupsid);
        }}
      >
        <HighlightOffIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Tooltip>
  );
}
```